# Как сделать скрин правого монитора?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Используется два монитора. Как можно сделать скрин с экрана правого монитора?

```
Sub screenshot_255_mm_full22222()

' вставка скриншота шириной 255 мм
'
'Selection.InsertRowsBelow 1 'вставка строки таблицы снизу
'Selection.TypeParagraph 'вставка абзаца
Dim oshp As Shape
Selection.Paste ' вставить из буфева
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend 'выделить слева от курсора
For Each oIshp In Selection.InlineShapes
           With oIshp

                              .Line.Weight = 1 'Ширина линии обводки в пт
                              .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(166, 166, 166) 'Цвет линии обводки
                                                                       'RGB(166, 166, 166) - Светло-серый оттенок 35%
                                                                       'RGB(255, 0, 0) - Красный
                              .Line.Visible = msoTrue 'Включить обводку
                              '.PictureFormat.CropTop = 100 'Величина обрезки рисунка в пт сверху
                              .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 29 'Величина обрезки рисунка в пт снизу
                              '.PictureFormat.CropLeft = 140.2 'Величина обрезки рисунка в пт слева
                             .PictureFormat.CropRight = 1440 'Величина обрезки рисунка в пт справа
                              .Width = 487.5 'Ширина картинки в пт
                                             '1 пт = 0.352(7) мм

           End With
       Next oIshp
End Sub
```

Пример кода для скрина левой части

Comment: в общем случае - никак. Мониторы могут быть расположены один над другим или просто перепутаны местами. Для начала определитесь, что такое правый монитор (это не всегда тот, который от Вас справа). Потом EnumDisplayDevices + CreateDC вместо GetDC

Comment: Дело в том, что этот макрос делает скрин левого монитора. Пример ниже

Comment: а содержимое скрипта предлагаете угадать?

Comment: )) Нет, я в вопросе добавил

Comment: Макрос работает, но vba никогда не писал.

Comment: Как вариант, вы можете переместить необходимые данные на левый экран и сделать скрин :)

Comment: )) Совет хороший.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот этой строке кода необходимо заменить CropRight на CropLeft:

```
.PictureFormat.CropRight = 1440 'Величина обрезки рисунка в пт справа
```

**Результирующая строка, которая подарит счастье от скрина на правом экране монитора:**

```
.PictureFormat.CropLeft= 1440 'Величина обрезки рисунка в пт слева
```